# How to order data from firebase using timestamp in android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to order items from firebase by timestamp. Then I would like to sum the total price so far I have managed to list the products inside a recyclerview, but they are not ordered

```
private fun getProductData(){
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Products")
dref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            for (productSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                val product = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductData::class.java)
                productList.add(product!!)
            }
            prodList.adapter = productAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
})
```

if someone can help me order them, and if possible show me how to find the sum of the price. I have read many docs but they don't ring the bell.

[image: Thisithe structure of my collections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order the child nodes you'll want to use a query as shown in the documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data):

```
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Products")
val query = dref.orderByChild("prodTime")

query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
  ...
```

Comment: Still my latest post is not at the top